# How to push flat data with POST in nested serializer DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API that can create testruns, but I need an instrument serial number to create it.

I would like to be able to have this POST request :

```
{
    "serial_number":"4331214L"
    "operator": "John Doe"
}
```

But, right now I have to do :

```
{
    "instrument": {
        "serial_number":"4331214L"
    },
    "operator": "John Doe"
}
```

current models:

```
class InstrumentModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "instruments"
        verbose_name = "Instrument"

    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial_number


class TestRun(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "test_runs"
        verbose_name = "Test run"

    operator = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(InstrumentModel, related_name="instruments", db_column="instrument", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=timezone.now)
```

I tried with the depth meta field. That doesn't work. Maybe it's not at the serializer level?

```
class TestRunSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    instrument = InstrumentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TestRun
        fields = ('operator', 'instrument')
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        serial_number = validated_data.pop('serial_number')
        instrument, _ = InstrumentModel.objects.get_or_create(serial_number=serial_number)
        return TestRun.objects.create(**validated_data, instrument=instrument)
```

Comment: have you tried with a RelatedField, like `serial_number = serializers.RelatedField(
        source='instrument.serial_number'
    )`
In the TestRunSerializer?

Comment: What happens when the queryset is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be right like that if you used [`to_internal_value`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_internal_valueself-data)

```
class TestRunSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    instrument = InstrumentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TestRun
        fields = ('operator', 'instrument')
        depth = 1
   def to_internal_value(self, data):
        serial_number = obj.get('serial_number')
        if not serial_number:
             raise serializers.ValidationError({
            'serial_number': 'This field is required.'
        })
        data['insturment'] = {'serial_number': serial_number}
        return data
```

Comment: {
    "instrument": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
        ]
    }
}

That's what I get

Comment: Sorry I've got that you need to edit the response not the input one

Comment: I had to change the last line before the return statement obj['serial_number'] = serial_number